# Java 1.8 update 121 (1.8.0_121-b13) causing the Applet to crash

Tags: java-8

The java applet is crashing and the common error noticed is,

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../classes/META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement to use such an old build? Is it only with this build? Was there any change on the webserver? (files might have been read from the webserver in ./services by the applet plugin)

Comment: You can include a file in the jar of the applet? Then you can put a file in `/META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory` containing `javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try adding to the jar of the applet and test it out.